# How to find p value using estimate and standard error?

Tags: p-value

I am trying to check statement on p. 23 of [Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/)

> For example, consider two independent studies with effect estimates and standard errors of 25 ± 10 and 10 ± 10. The first study is statistically significant at the 1% level

in R

```
> estimate <- 25
> se <- 10
> z <- estimate / se
> z
[1] 2.5
```

*t* distribution converges to normal as sample size increases (Cassella Berger 2ed Exercise 5.18)

I then plug `z` to distribution function to get probability of observing any value equal to `|z|` or larger (*p* value) [ISL](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL) p. 67

```
> pnorm(2.5, lower.tail=FALSE)
[1] 0.006209665
```

Whereas if I use formula from method [3]

```
> exp(-0.717 * z - 0.416 * z * z)
[1] 0.01236977
```

Was 0.0062 due to poor approximation? Or it should not compute that way?

[3]: Lin J-T. Approximating the normal tail probability and its inverse for use on a pocket calculator. Appl Stat1989;38:69-70.

Comment: The approximation looks excellent to me: 0.01236977 is extremely close to twice 0.006209665.  The error is only 0.4%.  By the way, the approximation is the calculation of "method [3]", not `pnorm`!

Comment: @whuber thank you! I should have multiplied `pnorm` by 2 because *equal to or larger |z|* means two intervals ? oh, so `pnorm` is by definition calculation ?

Comment: If you're unsure what `pnorm` does, the first place to look is its help page, accessed *via* the command `?pnorm`.  If that's unclear--which is often the case, because many `R` help pages are overly terse--then experiment with it. For instance, you can plot it easily with `curve(pnorm(x), -3, 3)`.